# VSCode not setting variables from scanf and printf

Tags: c, variables, visual-studio-code

I have written a code for my study subject that should make a simple calculation in a recursive manner, but VSCode does not print it correctly or seems to not be able to set any variables... Sadly I am fairly new to using VSCode, so i only have some basic ideas but cannot find an answer what the issue might be...

My theory is, that it is a problem with the terminal, since the loop is working fine.

Here is what happens (german comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main()
{
    float x; //Ergebnisvariable, Anfangswert
    float t; //Hilfsvariable zur Berechnung 
    int a; //Zahl zur Berechnung
    int g; //Genauigkeit (Anzahl der Durchgänge)
 
    printf(" Berechnung einer der Quadratwurzel einer Ganzzahl mit dem Newtonschen Annäherungsverfahren:\n\n");

    printf("Für welche Zahl soll angenähert die Quadratwurzel errechnet werden?\n");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    printf("Genauigkeit wählen (1,2,3,4)\n");
    scanf("%i",&g);

    printf("Die Zahl ist %i und die Genauigkeit %i\n\n", &a, &g);
    printf("Starte Berechnung für %d in %d Schritten.\n\n", &a, &g);
// Berechnung
    for(int i=0; i<g; i++)
        {
            t = a;
            x = (0.5)*(t+(a/t));
            printf("Schritt Nr.: %d \n", &i);
            printf("x%d: %f \n\n",&i, &x);
        }
    printf("Endergebnis: %f \n\n", &x);
}
```

And this is what it prints after executing:

[VSCode Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLFfm.jpg)

Also there are multiple warnings I an unable to interprete:

[Warnings for execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipxbE.jpg)

As far as I can tell, there are no syntax issues or semantic issues, it just does not work.

Maybe I have set up VSCode in the wrong way, maybe it is my operating system, I don't know...

I am using Lubuntu and have multiple Compilers installed and tested them with the same results.

Edit:
Thanks for the helpful comments! I already altered the 1/2 bit to 0.5

I am not sure what I should use for printf - variables instead of &, as far as any of the sources I have checked it should be as I wrote it.

Comment: Paste code into the question as text. Do not post images of code. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that `printf()` doesn't take the `&` address-of operator for its operands. Check out the compiler warnings.

Comment: ...and those warnings are telling you: `%d` expects an integer value, but you are passing a pointer. So for example `printf("x%d: %f \n\n", &i, &x);` should be `printf("x%d: %f \n\n", i, x);` similar for others.

Comment: That resolved it! Easy issue, easy fix but - Thank you!